# latest version of pendulum.Interval()?

Tags: python, pendulum

I'm working with some code from a year or two ago and it has:

```
import pendulum
pendulum.Interval(minutes=1000)
```

This worked with pendulum version 1.5.0, but doesn't work with the latest version 2.0.5.  Is there an equivalent of `pendulum.Interval` in the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code used Interval to loop through a time range.  It looks like the latest version should be:

```
dt = pendulum.now()
dt.add(minutes=1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The pendulum Interval changed to Duration since version 2.0. This can be found here, [docu](https://pendulum.eustace.io/history/).
So the replacement to Interval is:

```
from pendulum import Duration
Duration(minutes=1000)
```

Comment: Oof they have a lot of breaking changes in their versions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :- pendulum.duration(minutes=1000)